# Duplicate / Copy records in the same MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have been looking for a while now but I can not find an easy solution for my problem. I would like to duplicate a record in a table, but of course, the unique primary key needs to be updated.

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO invoices
    SELECT * FROM invoices AS iv WHERE iv.ID=XXXXX
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM invoices)
```

the problem is that this just changes the `ID` of the row instead of copying the row. Does anybody know how to fix this ?

//edit: I would like to do this without typing all the field names because the field names can change over time.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The way that I usually go about it is using a temporary table.  It's probably not computationally efficient but it seems to work ok! Here i am duplicating record 99 in its entirety, creating record 100.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id = 99;

UPDATE tmp SET id=100 WHERE id = 99;

INSERT INTO invoices SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id = 100;
```

Hope that works ok for you!

Comment: I like it, one step in the middle to keep an eye on things

Comment: If you're copying a single record you could drop the where in both update and insert. Then you could just press up twice in the mysql console which would bring up the next to last operation in history, change the id in update which is convenient at the end, hit enter, press up, hit enter again without changing anything, then repeat the procedure for multiple copies. Much faster.

Comment: what in case when id 100 is already there. Secondlty if you choose any new id for your new row, and during the operation someone else insert a new row and then your id and the newly inserted id will be the same.  This is the bottle neck in this code have.

Comment: You can use NULL: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT bla FROM invoices WHERE bla;

UPDATE tmp SET id=NULL;

INSERT INTO invoices SELECT * FROM tmp;`

Comment: @TobiasBeuving `Column 'id' connot be null`

Comment: @Marcel Yes it can - what makes you think that it can't?

Comment: @TobiasBeuving That is a copy-pasted error message because I have `NOT NULL` set on `id`. I was just wondering if you had suggestions for this case. Is that considered bad practice?

Comment: @Marcel Ok that explains it :-). Whether it's bad practice really depends on the use case. For example: one might want to set 'id' to something other than an auto incremented integer.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for posting!  You can simplify this even more by removing the `WHERE id = 100;` from this line: `INSERT INTO invoices SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id = 100;`

Answer (score 91):

Alex's answer needs some care (e.g. locking or a transaction) in multi-client environments.

Assuming the `AUTO ID` field is the first one in the table (a usual case), we can make use of implicit
transactions.

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from invoices WHERE ...;
    ALTER TABLE tmp drop ID; # drop autoincrement field
    # UPDATE tmp SET ...; # just needed to change other unique keys
    INSERT INTO invoices SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp;
    DROP TABLE tmp;
```

From the MySQL docs:

> Using AUTO_INCREMENT: You can also explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

Comment: This put the record in with an ID of 0 for me, even though I have an AUTO_INCREMENT field. Changing it to null worked, so I suggest you change the code to use null instead of 0. I'm on MySQL 5.5.35 (Ubuntu).

Comment: @TylerCollier: `NULL` or `0` both are acceptable. Can you post screen shots of the issue by reproducing and share it on here.

Comment: My brain hurt trying to understand the neato subquery in line 4. Maybe this explanation helps: The destination table `invoices` contains an AUTO_INCREMENT `ID` field. The source table `tmp` does not. In order to get the needed 1:1 correlation during the insert, you specify a `0` as the first field of the select which is the destination table's AUTO_INCREMENT field. The `tmp.*` selects all the fields from the source table `tmp`. Perfect! You now have your 1:1 correlation. Awesome answer @Tim.

Comment: @RavinderReddy NULL and 0 are not the same - it is possible to have a record-id of 0 - use NULL for this sort of thing

Comment: **@TobiasBeuving**: I am well aware that `NULL` and `0` are not the same. Current context is on `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature. You can't insert a `0` or a `NULL` value into such fields. But when you use them as inputs into such field, next sequence value will be assigned to that field *auto*matically. And hence my comment. Proof on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d619f/1

Comment: **BIG WARNING!!** The `ALTER TABLE` causes an implicit transaction commit, even though it's on a temporary table. And, actually, you should do `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp;` to avoid the same on the final line, though it's too late by then.

Answer (score 15):

A late answer I know, but it still a common question, I would like to add another answer that It worked for me, with only using a single line `insert into` statement, and I think it is straightforward, without creating any new table (since it could be an issue with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` permissions):

```
INSERT INTO invoices (col_1, col_2, col_3, ... etc)
  SELECT
    t.col_1,
    t.col_2,
    t.col_3,
    ...
    t.updated_date,
  FROM invoices t;
```

The solution is working for `AUTO_INCREMENT` id column, otherwise, you can add `ID` column as well to statement:

```
INSERT INTO invoices (ID, col_1, col_2, col_3, ... etc)
  SELECT
    MAX(ID)+1,
    t.col_1,
    t.col_2,
    t.col_3,
    ... etc ,
  FROM invoices t;
```

It is really easy and straightforward, you can update anything else in a single line without any second update statement for later, (ex: update a title column with extra text or replacing a string with another), also you can be specific with what exactly you want to duplicate, if all then it is, if some, you can do so.

Comment: This is also a good basis for modifying some fields while copying. I just used `INSERT into wp_options SELECT NULL, 'theme_mods_twopress', option_value, autoload FROM wp_options where option_name = 'theme_mods_onepress';` to copy while increasing the entry (`AUTO_INCREMENT` `NULL` trick from above) and the `option_name` field as well.

Comment: Yes.. Good Idea for me. Thank You!!

Comment: The best solution

Answer (score 13):

You KNOW for sure, that the DUPLICATE KEY will trigger, thus you can select the MAX(ID)+1 beforehand:

```
INSERT INTO invoices SELECT MAX(ID)+1, ... other fields ... FROM invoices AS iv WHERE iv.ID=XXXXX
```

Comment: yes, but I do not want to type all the other fields (there are more or less 20, and they might change over time). I do not want to change the code everytime the tablestructre changes.

Comment: You'll have to. You better make a script that generates the SQL statement from a list of fields. It's trivial.

Comment: The only other alternative is to use an insert trigger (if mysql supports that).

Answer (score 11):

Your approach is good but the problem is that you use "*" instead enlisting fields names. If you put all the columns names excep primary key your script will work like charm on one or many records.

```
INSERT INTO invoices (iv.field_name, iv.field_name,iv.field_name
) SELECT iv.field_name, iv.field_name,iv.field_name FROM invoices AS iv     
WHERE iv.ID=XXXXX
```

Comment: However that means that you will have to change the code as soon as a field is added to or dropped from the table, which I personally find a MAJOR no-no. (Not always, but often enough.)

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to extend Alex's great answer to make it appropriate if you happen to want to duplicate an entire set of records:

```
SET @x=7;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM invoices;
UPDATE tmp SET id=id+@x;
INSERT INTO invoices SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

I just had to do this and found Alex's answer a perfect jumping off point!.  Of course, you have to set @x to the highest row number in the table (I'm sure you could grab that with a query).  This is only useful in this very specific situation, so be careful using it when you don't wish to duplicate all rows.  Adjust the math as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue, and this is what I'm doing:

```
insert into Preguntas  (`EncuestaID`, `Tipo` , `Seccion` , `RespuestaID` , `Texto` )  select '23', `Tipo`, `Seccion`, `RespuestaID`, `Texto` from Preguntas where `EncuestaID`= 18
```

Been Preguntas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Preguntas` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EncuestaID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tipo` char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Seccion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RespuestaID` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Texto` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=522 ;
```

So, the `ID` is automatically incremented and also I'm using a fixed value ('23') for `EncuestaID`.

Comment: sorry, I just realized you dont want to use the columns name, so this doesnt apply

Answer (score 1):

I needed this as well;  my solution was to use SQLYOG (free version) to export the desired record as SQL (creates an insert).

I then hand edited this to remove the id as this needs to be auto-generated and then copied the insert into SQLYog to execute it. This was painless. I guess plenty of other MySQL GUIs can do this as well.

This provides me with a record I can use for test purposes on a live system.

I now have this insert for reuse as well, as the table is rewritten daily.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation, main difference being to set the primary key field ("varname") to null, which produces a warning but works.  By setting the primary key to null, the auto-increment works when inserting the record in the last statement.

This code also cleans up previous attempts, and can be run more than once without problems:

```
DELETE FROM `tbl` WHERE varname="primary key value for new record";
DROP TABLE tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE varname="primary key value for old record";
UPDATE tmp SET varname=NULL;
INSERT INTO `tbl` SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the temporarily table to change the ID field to a bigint or so without the NOT NULL requirement, then set the ID to 0 in that temp table. After that add it back to the original table and the NULL will trigger the auto increment.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM x WHERE (id='123');
ALTER TABLE tmptable CHANGE id id bigint;
UPDATE tmptable SET id = NULL;
INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO invoices (ID, col_2, col_3, col_4, etc)
    SELECT ((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM invoices)+1), col_2, col_3, col_4, etc FROM invoices WHERE ID=XXXXX
```

or

```
INSERT INTO invoices (ID, col_2, col_3, col_4, etc)
    SELECT ((SELECT ID FROM invoices ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)+1), col_2, col_3, col_4, etc FROM invoices WHERE ID=XXXXX
```