# sql for inserting data into colum based on other column value

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO tableX (ColumnPk,column1, column2)
VALUES((SELECT  max(columnPk) from tableX)+1, 'Column1 value', 'Column2 Value')
```

I tried this but getting error 1093: You can't specify target table 'organizationmanagement' for update in FROM clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MySQL, can I copy one row to insert into the same table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039748/in-mysql-can-i-copy-one-row-to-insert-into-the-same-table)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `VALUES` when you're using the result of `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO tableX (ColumnPk, column1, column2)
SELECT max(columnPk)+1, 'Column value', 'Column2 value';
```

Is there a reason you didn't configure `columnPk` as an auto-increment column, so it would do this automatically?