# copy one row from a table to another and insert value of one column in same query

Tags: mysql, insert, copy

I am copying column1, column2 from table2 but want to insert value of column3 in table1 manually... what should i do? Please help

```
INSERT INTO table1( column1, column2, column3) 
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table2
WHERE  `id` =  '1'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like

```
INSERT INTO table1( column1, column2, column3) 
SELECT column1, column2, 'My String' as column3
FROM table2
WHERE  `id` =  '1'
```

Comment: Except this answer won't stand the test of time. When the number of columns change (or, better, when the names of the columns change), the query will fail even if the names were not of your interest in the given query. So, this is an one time only solution, not usable in code.

Comment: 1) The Number of columns dont matter. as you write the columns you want to fill. 2) when you change the column name... WTF. if you change column name you will have to adept the code . if you really one to use something like this in long lasting code its part of the process. This must be one of the stupids comments i have ever received.