# Php 5.5 hash API and hashing plain text passwords already in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hash, passwords

I found a solution to the problem referenced below that may help people using PHP PDO.   I tested it and it works but I'm not sure it is the cleanest code or the best.  Any improvements are welcome.

Here is the original problem for reference:

I want to hash passwords that are already in a MySQL database.   I can already hash new passwords using the php 5.5 hashing API but I want to know if there is a way to take all the old plain text passwords and convert them to bcrypt hashes.  I am thinking now of copying the passwords to a new row called 'hash' and, after checking that they copied correctly, convert them to hashes.  I am not sure how to copy the password row and rename it on the same table, or how to hash all of these most efficiently, though.

Any insight would be appreciated.

**Here is the solution:**

```
    <?
    // IMPORTANT: only call this script one time or you will double hash and the passwords input by your users won't work anymore

    // Get Configuration file
    require("configsecuresavedgames.php");

    // Connect to your server

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8" , $user, $pass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Upload new score
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// set variable $x to 1 to start at ID 1 and then update each row in a loop, adding 1 to the $x variable once done 

$x = 1; 
// Note: Change the statement below so that the number is larger to match the number of users in your database

while($x <= 100) {

// select hash for each row...
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT hash FROM $tname WHERE id = $x"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

// set $hash variable to hash (from database) for the respective row

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['hash'];
    $hash = $row ['hash'];
}

// update hash row with new hash data (note: prior to running the script make sure that you've copied all plain text passwords to the hash row in the database.


    $newhash = password_hash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "UPDATE securesavegames SET hash = '$newhash' WHERE id = $x";


     // Prepare statement
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stm->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo $stm->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";

    // add to $x so that the hash for the next 'id' will be updated, then the loop will continue.

 $x++;

}  
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: no. hash = meat grinder. a hash turns a cow into hamburger. There is no way to take the hamburger and turn it back into the original cow. You'll have to get your users to re-enter their passwords so they can be run through the new hash.

Comment: @MarcB I think the passwords he is referring to are already plain text.

Comment: ah well, right... in that case `update yourtable set new_hash = hash(old_password_field)`. You could do an in-place `set pw=hash(pw)`, but then you'd lose the original plaintext ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039748/in-mysql-can-i-copy-one-row-to-insert-into-the-same-table

Comment: Hi MarcB, So could I just run the above SQL query in phpmyadmin and get hashes for my passwords in a new 'hash' row?   That is what I'd like to do basically.

Comment: @MarcB - MySQl has no appropriate hash functions available to hash passwords. Even the `password()` function should not be used to hash passwords, instead one needs a slow key derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2 with a cost factor.

Comment: @brett - Your found solution is open to SQL-injection. You are calling `$dbh->prepare()` but there is nothing to prepare, because the parameters where already added to the SQL in an unsafe way.

Comment: Can injection occur even though there is no user input ( no form or POST data)?  I was only planning to run the script once and then remove it from my server.  Is this still a problem?   If this is prone to injection, what would be a better way?   Thanks for the input.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @brett - You are right, in this case it should be safe, assuming that the variable `$tname` is hardcoded also. Nevertheless this is not the idea of preparing a statement, use placeholders instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your passwords are in plain text, just pass them through the hash and you'll be set.

There's not an easy way to have one query do your update, because `password_hash` is a PHP function. You will have to fetch the values and then loop through them. Prepared statements help a lot with this.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT record_id, password FROM table';
 $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

 $sql = 'UPDATE table SET password = ? WHERE record_id = ?';
 $prep = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
 $prep->bind_param('si', $pass, $record);

 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      $pass = password_hash($row['password']);
      $record = $row['record_id'];
      $prep->execute();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass them through the hash if they are already in the database?   Is there a SQL query that will do this for all of the passwords at the same time?   I feel pretty good about the php script to hash passwords when users are adding their data but how do I take what's already in the database and run the passwords through the php 5.5 hashing API?  The passwords are in plain text (not hashed at all yet).

Comment: I updated it with a loop you could use. There's not an easier way because you can't mix PHP into an `INSERT SELECT` statement like that. If you want to break the loop up, just add `WHERE password NOT LIKE "$%"` to your initial query and just run it over and over until everything is updated

Comment: Thank you Machavity, but I have been getting the following error with the code and I'm not really sure what it means:  "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object..."   What is this referring to?   Thanks,

Comment: In my example, `$mysqli` is an [instance of the mysqli object](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I found an way that works with PDO.  I was having difficulty getting it to work with mysqli because I have less experience with it.   Where can I post my solution in case it is useful for others?