# How can I multiply records on mysql table quickly?

Tags: mysql, import, row-number, multiplication

I have a project assignment that need the big data. So, I decide to test mysql query performance with big data. I want to multiply one table on the database. I've try it before, but I got an very long process to multiply it.

First I've try to use INSERT INTO the table itself and I got long process.
Second, I've tried a different way, and I use mysqlimport to import 1 GB data and I got about 1,5 hours long.

So If I want to enlarge the mysql table, do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: multiply records meaning ? increase rows ? or individual record value multiplication ? what is your  logic behind first `INSERT` then `mysqlimport` ?

Comment: I want only want to multiply the rows on a table (only to make the table large). In the first INSERT I do INSERT INTO query to table itself so, the row numbers become double. And second I use mysqlimport and upload very large csv file to table. I've done both of it, and I still got very long process....

Answer (score 0):

Though this question should be flagged as **"not constructive"**. I will still suggest you something.

If your objective is **"only to make the table large"** as per your comment. Why taking all the trouble to insert duplicate OR mysqlimport . Instead search for and download free sample large databases and play around

https://launchpad.net/test-db/+download

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

If explicitly a particular table structure is needed, then run some DDL queries (ALTER TABLE) to shape those tables (downloaded) according to your wish

Comment: oh I forgot to say that I have to use a specified data, so I only want to multiply that data not another. Do you know the faster way?

Comment: To do that faster : Refer this link [row insert using phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039748/in-mysql-can-i-copy-one-row-to-insert-into-the-same-table/14723023#14723023)