# Can you duplicate a row without knowing the schema in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

A great way to duplicate a row in MySQL is to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` syntax.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tblExample WHERE pkey = 1234;
```

This is easy and straightforward, but from a code maintenance standpoint this is one more statement to keep track of if there are any schema changes. Suppose I add an additional column to the `tblExample` table, `col4`; now I have to remember to go back and update this SQL statement in my code. If I fail to do so, then I've just introduced a bug.

With this in mind, is there an easy to way to copy the whole row, whatever the schema may be, except for the primary key?

Comment: You can probably issue a query to first get the schema, then dynamically build the insert.

Comment: P.S. I assume you meant to write `INSERT INTO tblExample (col1, col2, col3)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Fixed.

Comment: If you don't know the schema, you don't know what is the primary key. You can try to do this in PHP or any other server side script. Otherwise, if you find the answer, please let me know.

Comment: "the schema, aside from the primary key" if you will. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039748/in-mysql-can-i-copy-one-row-to-insert-into-the-same-table

Comment: Why don't you try to create a script that queries all columns except for the primary key and let it generate the SQL for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat inelegant way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM realTable WHERE pk = 'something';
UPDATE tmpTable SET pk = 'something else' ;
INSERT INTO realTable SELECT * FROM tmpTable;
```

Comment: This is quite strange a requirement. Duplicating a row is the last thing I would want to do in a database. A 1-n relationship could be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Very much against best practices you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE thisField = "abcd"
```

Comment: it works only if both the table have same schema

Comment: OP wants to duplicate a row from the same table - but not duplicate the primary key. Your answer will not do what is requested - this will fail due to duplicated PK.

Comment: @PaulF, you're right, I didn't see the very last part about not duplicating the primary key.

Comment: @PaulF could Tingo just add an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement somehow? I'm not sure if that can be used dynamically (for all columns) or not.

Comment: @McAdam331: I think that would only update the duplicated row, it wouldn't insert an additional row.

Comment: You're right, the answer is in the question, my mistake.